# Android Studio Apps Launcher missing but installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, app-launcher

I have read some other question about this problem and after trying,editing and inspecting my manifest , my Apps Launcher still doesnt appear

here is my manifest :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.common.myappname">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MerchantActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_merchant"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SlidingTabsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_voucher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks, i appreciate any help offered.

Comment: after i tried install on some other devices too, on most of it it appear but on some devices it doesn't appear